# Derivation of $T(z)(TT)(w)$ in CFT

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to derive eq. (6.213) in Di Francesco's CFT book,
$$T(z)(TT)(w) \sim \frac{3c}{(z-w)^6}+\frac{(8+c)T(w)}{(z-w)^4}+\frac{3 \partial T(w)}{(z-w)^3}+\frac{4 (TT)(w)}{(z-w)^2}+\frac{\partial(TT)(w)}{z-w}.\tag{6.213}$$
I must have made an error, since my answer was
$$T(z)(TT)(w) \sim\frac{-3 c}{(w-z)^6}-\frac{8T(w)}{(w-z)^4}+\frac{5\partial T(w)}{(w-z)^3}-\frac{\partial^2 T(w)}{(w-z)}.$$
I have two confusions:

1. In his OPE for $\partial T(x) T(w)$ (eq. 6.212) he has a term $\partial(TT)(w).$ Where does this come from? If you differentiate the $TT$ OPE's from earlier in the book you don't get this term because the expansion is truncated at the non-singular terms. Why this time do we keep going?
2. He does not write the OPE for $T(x)\partial T(w)$ but just says you can get it from differentiation. However when I differentiate I get a $\partial^2 T(w)$ term that he must not have obtained. Why is this? What rule of differentiating OPEs am I breaking to get that term?

Comment: You can't use Wick contractions to determine this OPE. That works only in free theories for (generalized) free field operators. You need to use (6.206) of the yellow book.

Comment: @Prahar I am using that, the step in which I am disagreement with the book is the one immediately after the application of (6.206). I got to (6.211) but I dont have the final term of (6.212) and I don’t have the correct (unstated) TdT OPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some introductory sources are too quick to say that only singular terms matter in chiral OPEs. Yes, meromorphic functions are determined by their singularities but it may well be the case that one needs a finite number of regular terms in order to use the OPEs during intermediate steps. It is convenient to start by finding out what this number is.

Looking at equation (6.159), singular terms in the final answer will arise in three ways.

1. Going up to the first regular term in the $\partial T(x) T(w)$ OPE.
2. Going up to the second regular term in the $T(x) T(w)$ OPE in the first line.
3. Keeping only the first regular term in all OPEs of the second line.

The regular term in $A(x)B(w)$ is by definition $(AB)(w)$ so the second line yields
\begin{equation}
\frac{\frac{c}{2} T(w)}{(z - w)^4} + \frac{2 (TT)(w)}{(z - w)^2} + \frac{(T\partial T)(w)}{z - w}. \quad\quad (1)
\end{equation}
To tackle the first line, we plug in the known OPEs to get
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{c}{2} T(w)}{(x - w) (z - x)^4} + \frac{c}{(x - w)^5 (z - x)^2} + \frac{4T(w)}{(x - w)^3 (z - x)^2} + \frac{2\partial T(w)}{(x - w)^2 (z - x)^2} + \frac{2(TT)(w) + (x - w) Y}{(x - w) (z - x)^2} - \frac{2c}{(x - w)^6 (z - x)} - \frac{4T(w)}{(x - w)^4 (z - x)} - \frac{\partial T(w)}{(x - w)^3 (z - x)} + \frac{(\partial TT)(w)}{(x - w) (z - x)}. \quad\quad (2)
\end{align}
I am being lazy with the $Y$ because I don't want to figure out what the second regular term in $T(x) T(w)$ is but we will come back to that.

Integrating (2) and adding it to (1), we get exactly the desired answer up to the $\frac{1}{z - w}$ term because we haven't solved for $Y$ yet. But this term *needs to be* the derivative of whatever $T(z)$ is acting on because the stress tensor generates translations. For more about how certain terms in stress tensor OPEs are universal (even when nothing is a Virasoro primary), see [a previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/648989/opes-from-spacetime-lorentz-invariance-of-the-polyakov-action).

Comment: Thanks! I wonder before I accept the answer if you know what the issue is regarding the appearance of $\partial^2 T(w)$ when computing the OPE for $T(x) \partial T(w)$?

Comment: Yes. It's totally there but it appears beside $(x - w)^{-1}$. Therefore, after using equation (6.159) you will get zero because there will be too many "factorials of negative integers" in the denominator.

Comment: I'm sorry, although I completed the exercise in the book where we prove (6.159) I have no idea what you mean by too many factorials of negative integers. The right-hand-side of that equation will be nonzero so long as the function $F(w)$ does not contain zeros at the same point, right? (If $F(w) = (x-w)^2$ while $n = 1$ then I understand that the integrand will have no singularities and the result will be zero)

Comment: They wrote $F(w)$ rather than $F(w, x)$ for a reason... $F(w)$ is to be thought of as the local operator you're working with and all powers of $(x - w)$ should be accounted for by adjusting $n$. What I'm saying is that you can set $m = 0$, $n = 2$ and $F(w) = \partial^2 T(w)$ and then the whole thing will be zero.

Comment: Oh, okay, so the powers $m, \, n$ that actually result are those for which no residues are associated with the $\partial^2 T$ term? To be honest I don't use (6.159), I just series expand in Mathematica.

Comment: Exactly. When $m = 0$, there is only a residue for $n = 1$.